# SharePoint Web Services Team Discussion and Replies

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to get a discussion with all it's replies from the sharepoint web services but only seem to be able to get the root message and not any of the replies.  Below is the soap XML.  What am I missing?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:GetListItems>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:listName>Team Discussion</soap:listName>

         <soap:viewFields>
                <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
            <FieldRef Name='ItemChildCount'/>
            <FieldRef Name='Body'/>
        </ViewFields>
         </soap:viewFields>
         <soap:queryOptions>
        <QueryOptions>
           <Folder>
        "http://Lists/Team Discussion/Bite Me"
       </Folder>
        </QueryOptions>
         </soap:queryOptions>

      </soap:GetListItems>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The reply is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
         <GetListItemsResult>
            <listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
               <rs:data ItemCount="2">
                  <z:row ows_Title="Hello" ows_ItemChildCount="3;#1" ows_Body="&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClass7B4989B3DC264716AD81B9CE55FD38FA&quot;>&lt;p>​The text of the message&lt;/p>&lt;/div>" ows_MetaInfo="3;#" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_ID="3" ows_UniqueId="3;#{6AF6D7DA-0D87-45EC-B002-AA0D153B6286}" ows_owshiddenversion="1" ows_FSObjType="3;#1" ows_Created="2012-01-11 12:21:26" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Modified="2012-01-11 12:21:26" ows_FileRef="3;#Lists/Team Discussion/Hello"/>
                  <z:row ows_Title="Bite Me" ows_ItemChildCount="1;#1" ows_Body="&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClass76A3DB4368714038B6B75DB0D807240B&quot;>&lt;p>​Really?&lt;/p>&lt;/div>" ows_MetaInfo="1;#" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_ID="1" ows_UniqueId="1;#{336518DC-B806-4DFB-9483-AB8DBB6258B6}" ows_owshiddenversion="1" ows_FSObjType="1;#1" ows_Created="2012-01-09 14:16:29" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Modified="2012-01-09 14:16:29" ows_FileRef="1;#Lists/Team Discussion/Bite Me"/>
               </rs:data>
            </listitems>
         </GetListItemsResult>
      </GetListItemsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

EDIT: Each of the above posts should also have a reply.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint was this?

Comment: I'm working with 2010 atm haven't tried 2007 but will need to at some stage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found the magic query.  It seems sub folders are only returned when you add a query based on date, i.e. this soap request works.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:GetListItems>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:listName>969E0130-5727-4E7D-A908-B3A5BC447E24</soap:listName>

         <soap:viewFields>
                <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
            <FieldRef Name='Created'/>
            <FieldRef Name='Author'/>
            <FieldRef Name='Body'/>
        </ViewFields>
         </soap:viewFields>

         <soap:query>
           <Query>
        <Where>
            <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name='Created' />
                <Value Type='DateTime'>2010-08-20T14:00:00</Value>
            </Geq>
        </Where>
        <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ThreadIndex' Ascending='true' /></OrderBy>
      </Query>
         </soap:query>

    <soap:queryOptions>
           <QueryOptions>
        <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll" IncludeRootFolder="False" />
       </QueryOptions>
         </soap:queryOptions>
      </soap:GetListItems>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The essential parts are the query element with the date and the query option to specify the query is recursive.

imho shouldn't need the query as it should return everything by default.

The folder option listed in the other article didn't make any difference for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this article:

How to access SharePoint's Discussion Board using Web Services
http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2007/03/12/108545.aspx

Comment: Yeah doesn't work for me I just get the top level even using the folder option and if you read the MSDN documentation the folder query option he uses is only a filter